# How to set PGOPTIONS when starting Postgres using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to start a Postgres database using `docker-compose` and pass some configurations using the [`PGOPTIONS` environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/config-setting.html). My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpw
     - PGOPTIONS='-c track_activities=on -c track_counts=on -c track_io_timing=on'
```

When I start this service using `docker-compose up db` I get:

```
db_1   | FATAL:  parameter "track_io_timing" requires a Boolean value
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | FATAL:  parameter "track_io_timing" requires a Boolean value
db_1   | psql: FATAL:  parameter "track_io_timing" requires a Boolean value
```

It does not seem to be related to the `tracking_io_timing` parameter, because when I remove that one from the `PGOPTIONS` variable I get the same error, but for the `track_counts` variable. So I suspect there is something wrong with the way I declared `PGOPTIONS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same result here when using your provided Docker-Compose file. I have tried to use the alternative syntax for defining environment variables and I do not get the errors anymore:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dbpw
      PGOPTIONS: "-c track_activities=on -c track_counts=on -c track_io_timing=on"
```

Comment: This made it work for me. Unfortunately it looks like PGOPTIONS ist not interpreted by the server. It seems to be that only the psql client interprets these values.

Answer (score 0):

As of PostgreSQL 16, you can use the environment variable `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS` to set server parameters that will be installed in `postgresql.conf` using `-c name=value` or `--set name=value` (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html#APP-INITDB-OPTION-SET)).

This also works for parameters that would normally require a server restart (e.g. `max_prepared_transactions`).

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my-database-name
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "-c max_prepared_transactions=100"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

```bash
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w my-database-name -c "SHOW ALL;" | grep 'max_prepared_transactions'
# max_prepared_transactions | 100 | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously prepared transactions.
```